# How can I style the response that I send from app.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I was trying to build a simple weather web app which tells about the temperature of entered place with API via openweathermap.org.
I want to style the response I send to users.
Here's the js code

```
  response.on("data", (d) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(d); //converting into javascript objects
      const des = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      const tempr = weatherData.main.temp;
      const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const weatherUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";

      res.write("<h1>" + city + " has " + des);
      res.write(" and the Temperature is:" + tempr + "degrees Celcius</h1>");
      res.write("<img src=" + weatherUrl + ">");
      res.send();
```

This works fine but appears as a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the MIME type ([`response#type`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.type))

```
response.on("data", (d) => {
    const weatherData = JSON.parse(d); //converting into javascript objects
    const des = weatherData.weather[0].description;
    const tempr = weatherData.main.temp;
    const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
    const weatherUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";

    res.type("html");
    res.write("<h1>" + city + " has " + des);
    res.write(" and the Temperature is:" + tempr + "degrees Celcius</h1>");
    res.write("<img src=" + weatherUrl + ">");
    res.send();
```

otherwise the browser interprets the response as plain text.

Comment: The plain text appearing says the temperature and weather condition of the entered city which is fine but I want to add style to the page which appears as a response.

Comment: @BidishaPandit The response appears styled with the correct MIME type: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gic3bt?file=index.js